# Loading StreamedContent for p:media after postback throws java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to upload a pdf file in jsf but before upload I would wish to allow user to see preview of the pdf before hitting submit button but its failing and giving this error message in chrome

[image]

and is the stack trace I get when I try preview pdf using chrome browser

```
24-Feb-2021 20:29:57.256 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-255] com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError java.io.FileNotFoundException: demo_receipt.pdf (The system cannot find the file specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at co.sf.controller.UploadController.load_stream_Content(UploadController.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
```

and this is my managed bean code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package co.sf.controller;

//imports

@ManagedBean(name = "userData", eager = true)
@SessionScoped
public class UploadController implements Serializable {

  

    public UploadController() {
    }
    
    StreamedContent streamedContent;

    public void load_stream_Content() throws Exception {
        Path fileName = Paths.get(image.getSubmittedFileName());
       String path= fileName.toString();
  
        FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

        if (context.getCurrentPhaseId() == PhaseId.RENDER_RESPONSE) {
          
            streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent();
        } else {
          String fs = Paths.get(image.getSubmittedFileName()).getFileName().toString(); 
          

         
            streamedContent=new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(new File(path)), "application/pdf", fs);//error is occuring here
          
        }
        streamed = true;
    }

    boolean streamed = false;

    public boolean isStreamed() {
        return streamed;
    }
```

and here is my jsf page

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
     
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div id="upload-button">
                <p>Browse</p>
                <h:inputFile   value="#{userData.image}">
                    <f:passThroughAttribute name="accept" value="*.pdf"/>
                    <f:ajax event="change" listener="#{userData.load_stream_Content}"  render=":pdf_preview"/>
                </h:inputFile>
            </div>
             <h:commandButton value="Upload" action="#{userData.doUpload()}">
                           <f:ajax  execute="@form" render="@form"/>
             </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        
        
               <p:media id="pdf_preview" rendered="#{userData.streamed}"  width="100%" height="700px" value="#{userData.streamedContent}"
            cache="false" player="pdf"/>
      
        
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JasperdeVries kindly check the error has changed and I rectivied the code as suggested in the duplicate code and did not work

Comment: @JasperdeVries how does the duplicate questions resolves my question??

Comment: @BalusC am a newbie in jsf and cant relate what you recommended with my post

Comment: @BalusC My uploads works fine so my concern is I don't want to save the file first without preview and that why I posted this question. If you are kind enough you can help me resolve it will really appreciate

Comment: @BalusC I need immediately a user click on browse button he should see a preview of what he has selected before hitting upload button

Comment: @BalusC what do u mean by bytes[] would you kindly show me. am completely stuck on this from yesterday